# Infopath similar functionality on asp.net web form

Tags: html, asp.net, infopath

I am looking for a similar control where i can generate a web page html(tables,css styles) using drag and drop functionality on the web page, Is there any control or functionality where i can give customers to design there own html template on the web page

Thanks

Comment: are you searching for control or IDE  or prototype ?

Comment: control which allows us to drag html <table> or <img> elements on the asp.net webpage

Comment: create table on asp.net webpage using drag and drop from any other third party control